# Is the adjective "maledetto" current usage in Italian? Where in Italy is it used?

Tags: word-usage, regional

The adjective "maledetto" is translated into English as "accursed", "damned" or "cursed".  Is it current usage in Italian?  Is it a regional term?  Is it a swearword?

Comment: It's a normal, standard Italian word. What makes you single it out?

Comment: @DaG  A few years ago there was an Italian tourist using it all the time here where I live. Another Italian who has lived here for a long time said it's a regionalism and that most people in northern Italy never use it.

Comment: It has nothing regional; it's an adjective derived from the past participle of *maledire* (to curse), and the corresponding noun is *maledizione* (curse). Normal, Italian words.

Comment: @Centaurus I am from northern Italy and I use it often. I have no idea why anyone would tell you it is a regionalism.

Comment: @DenisNardin  Nor do I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Collins Dictionary entry may be helpful also. Note that the usage is mainly in the figurative sense in common contermporary speech.

[Maledetto](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/maledetto)

*past participle of verb **maledire***
(adjective)

> - ***(dannato)*** accursed
> - ***(nelle imprecazioni)*** cursed, damned
> - ***(figurative, informal)*** damned, blasted, confounded
>
>   - *avere una fame maledetta to be damned hungry*
>   - *spegni quella maledetta radio! turn off that damn radio*!
>   - *ho una paura maledetta dei ragni I'm scared stiff of spiders*
>   - *è stato un giorno maledetto it's been a bloody awful day*
>   - *non vedo l'ora di finire questo maledetto lavoro I can't wait to finish this damn work.*

Comment: Can I use it with reference to "food", "radio", "spiders", "cold weather", whatever bothers me, without offending anyone?

Comment: Yes, though in the case of food it would sound offensive to those who prepared it. You would probably say "cibo maledetto" if it made you feel bad.

Comment: Written Italian is sometimes very easy for me to understand.  "Não vejo a hora de terminar este maldito trabalho"  would be the Portuguese translation of your last sentence.

Answer (score 5):

***Maledetto*** is a perfectly correct and widely used word with the meanings you suggested.

It is not technically a swearword but rather an expression of outburst, sometimes with an irritated tone sometimes joking, towards someone else that is procuring you bother or annoyance:

*Cosa pretende ancora da me, quel **maledetto**?* 
(What does that unbearable man expect from me yet?)

and in a more colloquial form:

*Vinci sempre tu a poker, **maledetto***!
(You always win when playing poker, bastard!)

Another use is with a religious meaning, and in this case the English translation would be *cursed, damned*:

Andate via da me, ***maledetti***, nel fuoco eterno preparato per il diavolo e i suoi angeli
(Depart from me, you who are cursed, into the eternal fire prepared for the devil and his angels)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes *maledetto!* is used often as a funny or friendly way to say something like *you are smarter than me!* That way is often used as a joke, there I could understand what your Italian friend said saying that his use was "regional".

Answer (score 0):

I would also say that it is pretty common, but not amongst the newer generations. They use different words to convey the various meanings of *maledetto* and these are in many cases vulgarisms.